# Extruding / Raising Specific Areas

Tags: modeling, mesh, extrude

I've been trying to get better at making armors in Blender, starting with helmets. The one thing I can't seem to wrap my head around is the correct / a proper way of going about extruding / raising certain areas when the geometry of the area isn't perfect itself.

My main trouble has been around the eyes of a helmet. I want to add some depth around the eyes and I can't seem to come up with a better way than adding a ton of loop cuts to be able to create a desired area good enough to extrude.

I created a quick example of what I'm referring to. Most of my helmets don't have perfect geometry, I seem to end up with quite a bit of triangles, so it's near impossible for me to extrude some of those projects.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated ahead of time. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you mean by "*perfect geometry*" or "*proper way of going about extruding*". There is no "proper way" you simply extrude and it is either the result you expect or not.

Could you be looking for a tool to extrude along each face normals?

Try selecting a bunch of faces and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> > *Region (Vertex Normals).

[image]

Comment: [link](https://ibb.co/hJaQAQ)

I'm very sorry, I'm terrible at explaining things in general and my knowledge of Blender / 3D Modeling terms are limited. Ok in your quick video you made, you have the easy selection of choosing which faces you want to extrude. On some of my models, I have triangles and faces that are uneven and don't perfectly line up, some because of triangles. I created a quick model to simulate what I'm referring to.

Sorry I couldn't find out how to place an image in the comments without a link.

Comment: What you have is a terrible topology problem, and in that case my answer addresses nothing to solve your problem. You can't just blindly make a helmet out of a mostly orthogonal grid. Your edges must follow the shape of your wholes and flow with its curvature. There is no recipe, nothing we say here can help you other than learning [good topology](http://topologyguides.com) practices.